# Can set a property for an interface but not for the object descended from it (Speech API)

Tags: vb.net, interface, speech

I am using SAPI speech recognition

this works!

```
Dim reco As ISpRecognizer
reco.SetRecognizer(reognizer as speechlib.ispobjectoken)
```

but this doesn't!!!

```
Dim reco As SpInprocRecognizer
reco.setrecognizer... NO SUCH PROPERTY!
```

What can I do to tell my recognizer what engine to use?

Comment: Any reason that you're not using the .NET speech API?

Comment: This is COM we're talking about so it's not the same as .NET. I think that you may actually have to cast the object as type `ISpRecognizer` to access members of that type. I don't use COM much but I'm fairly sure that I had to do that with a web browser object to access members of a specific HTML interface.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yes, 2 reasons. It seems like too much of an abstraction over SAPI. My understanding is that it is just a managed wrapper over SAPI (could be wrong) and 2. spent 2 months trying to get help here, elsewhere and from Microsoft and could never get an answer on how to set the audio input to a wave driver by its device ID (MMSYSTEM) See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Server-for-Developers/How-can-I-set-an-audio-input-device-for-Speech-SDK-v-11/td-p/84431. Would still love an answer to that one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Would you have an idea on how to do this? MSDN says that ISpRecognizer is an interface and there are two objects that implement that interface through COM, SpInProcRecognizer and SpSharedRecognizer. So I don't know if I have to somehow set my SpInProceRecognizer to spanish, or set the ISpRecognizer and it automatically knows in my shared recognizer, or if I have to link the 2 somehow so that the inproc recognizer uses the same engine, or if I have to somehow duplicate manually what SpInProcRecognizer does by setting properties and callign methods in ISpRecognizer

Comment: Like I said, I don't work with COM much so I'm no expert but, unlike .NET interfaces, I think that COM interfaces require that you cast as that type to access members of that type. Actually it's just like an explicit interface implementation in C#. You cast using DirectCast, just like always.